# Greater Than and Less Than Symbols in C# Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex

I am using a Regex pattern `"MilliSeconds\s\&lt;"` and try to compare with the input `"MilliSeconds <"` but everytime my Regex match is getting failed. Can anyone tell what is wrong here?

MilliSeconds  followed by backslash and `&lt;`

```
string value = @"MilliSecs <Test Run";
string pattern = @"MilliSecs\s\&lt;";

Match mtchObj = Regex.Match(value,pattern);

if(mtchObj.Success)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Matched");
}
```

Which my input string is not getting matched with the pattern?

Comment: no need to escape `<` :- `MilliSeconds\s<`

Comment: put more code telling what is happening and what you expect..

Comment: Can you modify the `pattern`? Try `@"MilliSeconds\s(?:&lt;|<)"`. If not, there is a more serious problem. Please check if my question edit is appropriate. (**comment updated**)

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Can you please put it as answer so that i can mark it as  answer. It works but can you please tell me the reason behind it

Comment: Good, so, my edit is proper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the regex engine does not know of XML escaped strings, and `&lt;` does not stand both for a `&lt;` string and `<` character. In other words, these *entities* are not identical for the regex engine.

It appears you *can* modify the `pattern`. Note that it is possible to match either `<` or `&lt;` with the help of *alternation* and *grouping*:

```
@"MilliSeconds\s(?:&lt;|<)"
                ^^^^^^^^^^
```

So, `(?:&lt;|<)` is  a non-capturing group that tries to match `&lt;` and if it is not found, `<` is tried.

Answer (score 1):

Use simply `string pattern = @"MilliSecs\s<";`, there is no need to escape `<` in this regex since it doesn't have a special meaning. You code should be:

```
string value = @"MilliSecs <Test Run";
string pattern = @"MilliSecs\s<";

Match mtchObj = Regex.Match(value,pattern);

if(mtchObj.Success)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Matched");
}
```

Comment: But my pattern reads "\&lt;" not the symbol "<", can't change my input file

Comment: What if you gave us your raw data, so we can try ? @karthik

Comment: My pattern will look like this  <Pattern Value="MilliSecs\s\&lt;(\w|[._-])+&gt;\s\(" InitString="MilliSecs\s\&lt;" EndString="\s\(" /> . I will do the Init and end string comparison and if matches go ahead with regex comparison . What happens is the my string comparison goes through but my regex fails ?